# Converting variable values to strings so i can perform calculations

Tags: php, string, integer

I have two variables which are

```
$product['productsPrice']
```

which contains $15.40
and

```
$product['productsPriceEach']
```

which contains $7.70

I need to be able to perform a simple calculation of

```
$new_value = $product['productsPrice'] - $product['productsPriceEach']
```

but no matter what i try i can't get anything other than 0 as an answer.

I tried using

```
(int)$product['productsPrice']
```

also tried 
    (float)$product['productsPrice']
I then tried assigning $product['productsPrice'] to a new var so that i could test

```
(int)$productsPrice
```

or 
    (float)$productsPrice.

Then I used str to drop the $ sign and tried (int) and (float) again but still get 0 as a result.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Take a look at this answer in another post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5059851/1236086

Comment: Or you could simply exclude the dollar sign from the price and then concatenate it with the new calculated price.

Comment: @andersevenrud This post helped to resolve my issue. Thank you for the link